# Combine two inputs and a string in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script to add a description line to a `.htaccess` file.

Specifically, I want to take two inputs where one is the description and the other is the file path. All of this has to go after `AddDescription`. I need this to output one string that I can then add to a file.

All together, it should come out to something like this:

```
AddDescription description path
```

How can I do it?

Comment: ...What's the problem you're getting with your current code? *Where* is your current code?

Comment: Please indicate what did you try so far and where you are stuck. This should very basic.

Answer (score 1):

with echo you can achieve this

```
 echo AddEscription $var $PATH
```

if you want to write a script for this, there is no need to specify number of arguments. Create an executable file with these contents and run with as many arguments as you want

```
#!/bin/bash
echo AddEscription "$@"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

`RESULT=$(paste <(echo "AddDescription") <(echo "$DESCRIPTION_VAR") <(echo "$PATH_VAR") -d ' ')`

and then

```
echo $RESULT
```

assuming that you assigned your first input to `$DESCRIPTION_VAR` and your second input to `$PATH_VAR`.

Comment: Wow, four processes to replace a simple `printf`?